# Fluid simulation only shows the domain

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, baking, fluid-simulation

I was making a fluid simulation, but when I try to bake it, it only bakes the domain. The fluid doesn't appear from the inflow. Do you know why? Thanks.[image]

This is what appears when i render
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "only bakes the domain", but try to change Start and End values to something in seconds, not frames

Comment: The fluid domain object is turned into the fluid mesh when it is baked, any inflows/outflows will add/remove volume from fluid the fluid domain object

Comment: I add a photo of what appears when rendered

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely because of the time settings. Setting it to a frame value will make it think that the simulation happens 179 seconds after the start of the animation. What's this? Like frame 600? Change it to a small value that compensates with your animation time (in seconds), and your problem should be solved. You may even want to check the animation timeline 179 seconds later, and you will probably see your fluid.